# Jquery focus on first text field and set cursor at value end for instant data entry

Tags: jquery, focus

I am loading a form and defaulting focus to the first text field. The text field is populated with a default value "PW-". (The first characters of the customers part number like PW-446, PW-9887)

They want to just start typing the numbers upon form load instead of clicking to the end of the field, etc to type numbers. The cursor should be blinking at the end of the PW-  and ready to go for data input.

I have tried many different methods found on StackOverflow with no luck :-(
Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input:text:first').focus();

});
```

**HTML**

```
< input type="text" name="part_id" size="20" value="PW-">
```

Comment: Did you see this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056359/set-mouse-focus-and-move-cursor-to-end-of-input-using-jquery

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's an [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cG9gN/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = $("input:text").get(0);
    var elemLen = el.value.length;

    el.selectionStart = elemLen;
    el.selectionEnd = elemLen;
    el.focus();
});​
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Property/selectionStart

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Property/selectionEnd

For older versions of IE you may need to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536401(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: FWIW, the focus() should always be done on a visible element otherwise it will not work. Meaning, you need to focus on an element AFTER an element is visible and not before.

Comment: Lovely. All the other examples of similar questions here on SO did not work for me. Yours does.

Comment: @Matheretter - Glad to hear it :D

Answer (score 0):

Something a little different: maybe try setting your "PW-" just in text to the left of the text input field.  Validate against non-numbers in the field and then when submitting the form, prepend the "PW-" to that field's value, so that you have a complete part number.