# How to fix UI issue when Cursor set to last position of textbox in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I have a big problem which I tried to find fix for but didn't work so finally posting here.
[Visit this link](http://codetheory.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/caret_on_focus.png) to see the UI issue present in the Chrome. IDEALLY the BLUE COLORED textbox is how the UI should look like. But when I keep on adding elements and as the size grows for textbox it doesn't show last text instead it shows data like NON BLUE COLORED textboxes even though CARET is position is at last of textbox.
I am using this code.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
];
function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( ", " );
            focusCampo(this.id);
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function focusCampo(id) {
var inputField = document.getElementById(id);
if (inputField != null && inputField.value.length != 0) {
    if (inputField.createTextRange) {
        var FieldRange = inputField.createTextRange();
        FieldRange.moveStart('character', inputField.value.length);
        FieldRange.collapse();
        FieldRange.select();
    } else if (inputField.selectionStart || inputField.selectionStart == '0') {
        var elemLen = inputField.value.length;
        inputField.selectionStart = elemLen;
        inputField.selectionEnd = elemLen;
        inputField.focus();
    }
} else {
    inputField.focus();
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
<input id="tags" size="50" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[JS Fiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/59YaL/23/)

Any sort of help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Can't find any issue with the provided jsfiddle sample

Comment: did u see it properly in chrome the caret is set at end but you don't see END text. try selecting actionscript 6~7 times. You will understand.

Comment: Took me some time to see it too - it's when you use the auto-complete to add suggested matches, the input won't 'scroll' the text to the caret/last position.

Comment: It is working perfectly when you type. but issue is there when you select a value from autocomplete box.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [Set mouse focus and move cursor to end of input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056359/set-mouse-focus-and-move-cursor-to-end-of-input-using-jquery)

Seems like moving the text to the caret with selection and focus only works when actually focusing (in your case the input doesn't loose it), so in the focusCampo function before the focus call simply add:

```
 inputField.blur();
```

Here's the modified fiddle and it seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/59YaL/25/

Comment: Hi @Damyan Petev Thanks for answer. It's working. Let me test it for a while then I will mark it as accepted answer :) thanks a lot.