# set mouse focus and move the cursor to the end of the input focus in a Rails js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have seen this topic, [set-mouse-focus-and-move-cursor-to-end-of-input-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056359/set-mouse-focus-and-move-cursor-to-end-of-input-using-jquery) but I cannot get it to work.

comments/edit.js.erb

```
def edit
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html
  end
end

<%= form_for @comment, url: photo_comment_path(@comment.photo_id, @comment), method: :patch, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.submit class: "hidden" %>
<% end %>
```

Rails automatically moves `:content` into the `input#comment_content`. If I call

```
$("input#comment_content").focus()
```

this brings the cursor into focus at the beginning of the string. I want it at the end of the string.

I have tried the following and several other combinations but nothing sticks:

```
var this = $('input#comment_content').val();
$('input#comment_content').val('');
$('input#comment_content').focus();
$('input#comment_content').val(this);
```

Comment: Don't use this as variable name. Try input.focus().val(input.val());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work, but it only works one way. You have to add a custom class to the input field and then use that as `'input#comment_content.class'`